# ASP .NET wrongly converts decimal numbers to hundreds after form request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I've created a MVC project and in the html code there's a Form with an input field of type="number", whenever I insert a decimal value (es: 10.4) and I post the form to the C# controller API (through a Command IRequest parameter), the decimal value gets automatically converted to a whole number, basically removing the dot (es: 10.4 becomes 104).
Why is that? Is there any way I can fix it?

Edit:
An example of the code I'm using:

In the View file the form is:

```
<form>
  ...
  <input type="number" asp-for="ModelFieldName" />
</form>
```

While in the c# controller i use this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> FormApi([FromQuery] GetFormEntity Query query, UpdateFormEntityCommand command) {
  ....
  await Mediator.Send(command);
  var model = await Mediator.Send(query);
  return await View("...", model);
}
```

Basically when the form Submits the Post Method gets called and the data is passed to the UpdateFormEntityCommand which is of type IRequest and handles the updates to the underlying entity, the problem is that every decimal value sent by the client (the web page) correctly (I checked with the Chrome dev tools and the value sent was correct with the dot) gets the dot completely removed (I checked using the debugger and the value in the command parameter was already wrong).

I also use jquery in this project so it maybe the one who is causing this problems but I don't think that's the case..

Comment: Can you post the html/js and the c# controllers/models related?

Comment: Can you share your view and api?I test with form data 10.4,it will not be 104.

Comment: Hello, I've added an example of the code I'm using, thank you for your help!

Comment: I have the issue as yours. Did you find what was causing this problem?

Comment: Hello, in the end my problem was client side, so I can't really help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [Step](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp) attribute to `any`. It defaults to `1`, which will only allow whole numbers.

```
<Input type="number" step="any">
```